# Random background change in Xojo

Tags: colors, background, xojo

I've tried to create a button in Xojo, so every time I press it the background color should randomly change. The name of my window is just Window1. I can't figure out how to do it. I would appreciate an example please. I know how to generate random colors, but how to do it with the background?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already tried to set the background color, please also ensure the `HasBackgroundColor` property of your window is set to `True`:

```
Self.HasBackgroundColor = True
Self.BackgroundColor = Color.Red // Use your random color variable instead
```